# Pass an image saved in state to Express JS as static image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I have a view that accepts a file (an image, for now) and previews it on the page.
The same view also has a form that accepts two text inputs. Currently, when submitted, the text inputs are sent, via axios, to my Express JS server to be displayed on a different view. I'd like the image that is chosen by the user to, also, be sent to the server and saved statically in a folder there (I'm not using a database yet).

My current attempt simply passes the same state the user image is in to the axios post request. However, this does not work and the view reloads and clears all data. I've not noticed any errors in the console.

How can I achieve my goal?

```
function sendVideo() {
  axios
    .post(`${BASE_URL}videos`, {
      title: document.getElementById("uploadTitle").value,
      description: document.getElementById("uploadDesc").value,
      image: this.state.file,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

class VideoUpload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file: null,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="uploadContainer">
        <section className="uploadContainer__titleContainer">
          <h2 className="uploadContainer__title">Upload Video</h2>
        </section>
        <section className="uploadContainer__detailsContainer">
          <input id="qwe" type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <img
            type="file"
            id="uploadImage"
            src={this.state.file}
            alt={this.state.file}
            className="uploadContainer__thumbnail"
          ></img>
          <div className="uploadContainer__formContainer">
            <form action="" className="uploadContainer__form" id="uploadForm">
              <h6 className="uploadContainer__text">TITLE YOUR VIDEO</h6>
              <input
                required
                id="uploadTitle"
                type="text"
                className="uploadContainer__uploadTitle"
                placeholder="Add a title to your video"
              />
              <h6 className="uploadContainer__text">ADD A VIDEO DESCRIPTION</h6>

              <input
                required
                id="uploadDesc"
                type="text"
                className="uploadContainer__uploadDesc"
                placeholder="Add a description to your video"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="uploadContainer__buttonSection">
          <div className="uploadContainer__cancelButton">CANCEL</div>
          <button
            form="uploadForm"
            type="submit"
            className="uploadContainer__uploadButton"
            onClick={() => sendVideo()}
          >
            <img
              className="uploadContainer__uploadIcon"
              draggable="false"
              src={uploadIcon}
              alt="upload-icon"
            />
            PUBLISH
          </button>
        </section>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Backend:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const path = require("path");
const videoJsonFileName = path.join(__dirname, "../data/videos.json");
const videos = require(videoJsonFileName);

const utils = require("../utils/utils");

router.get("/", (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(videos);
});

router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  const foundVideo = videos.find((video) => video.id === req.params.id);

  if (!foundVideo) {
    res
      .status(404)
      .json({ errorMessage: `Video with ID "${req.params.id}" was not found` });
  }

  res.status(200).json(foundVideo);
});

//CREATE A NEW OBJECT
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  //video title, desc, thumbnail 
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body.title || !req.body.description || !req.body.image)
    return res.status(400).json({
      errorMessage: "Please provde title, description, and image",
    });

  const newVideoObj = {
    title: req.body.title,
    image: req.body.image,
    description: req.body.description,
    id: utils.getNewId(),
  };

  utils.writeToJsonFile(videoJsonFileName, [...videos, newVideoObj]),
    res.status(201).json({ newVideoCreated: newVideoObj });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You haven't share your backend code, expressJs does not process multipart by itself, you'll need to add a middleware package for that. http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.properties

Comment: I added the backend code. My research did mention using middleware but was unfamiliar with what was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In your frontend:

```
//formData request body is used to handle file upload
const fd = new FormData();
//the file itself should be appended before any other value.
//file should be of type file or buffer

fd.append(<property name>, <propValue>);
//repeat above line for any additional fields, e.g. name, description etc.

axios.post(url, fd, [...options])
```

In your backend:
Firstly you'll need to install and require a module that handles multipart, such as [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).
your expressjs method will look something like this:

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post(<your-url>, upload.single("file"), <your handle function>...)
```

References: [formData (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), [express-multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)